# Does it really matter if the project library I use has a different minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from my main project

Tags: android

Currently, my main project is having the following configuration

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

I'm using ActionbarSherlock, Google Play services and Sliding menu libraries too. They are having different configuration.

### ActionbarSherlock

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
```

### Google Play services

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
```

### Sliding menu

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="5"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

I was wondering, is there any side effect, of letting my library projects having different different minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion? So far my testing is they work without problem. However, I might be missing out something else.

Also, what about case, of having one of the libraries, to have higher target SDK version than main project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is correct.

minSdkVersion defines requirements, and targetSdkVersion - 'recommend' requirements, which API your app aims. Thanks for backports of some feature - some functionalities like actions bar are available also for olders API.

In the case that you have different version in library - you should set minSdkVersion same as is in the library (your app is using this library, and minimum req for the library are defined trough its attribute).

It may work for you without this, but you may expect problems at some point.

Comment: What about the case, of one of the libraries is having higher target Sdk than my main project?

Comment: You should probably target the suggested sdk if it's higher, like 17.

Comment: Why can't you have different targetSdkVersion in Main project and Library project?